# NavigationController pushViewController takes a lot of CPU's usage

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have a navigationController set and whenever I push a new ViewController using

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(registrationViewController, animated: true)
```

The CPU usage of the app goes up to 100% for no reason.

I used Time Profiler to know better what was causing this CPU overuse, and I found out that the process **_CFRunLoopRun** is taking a lot of CPU capacity.

To be honest I don't know what could cause the problem since the presentation of the view controller and the viewcontroller itself it's really easy.

```
let registrationViewController = tryVC2()
navigationController?.pushViewController(registrationViewController, animated: true)
```

I also noticed that this only happens when I use pushViewController method, and ***not*** when I use presentViewController.

I would really appreciate If you could point me in the right direction in order to solve this problem.

EDIT:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: *the process _CFRunLoopRun* - this is a top process, you should open this process and go deeper in `TimeProfiler`, so you can see what is consumed CPU

Comment: you can try `DispatchQueue.main { /*push*/ }`

Comment: @Kirow, tried it, doesn't change the problem

Comment: @vpoltave I did it and added the screenshot in EDIT

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. I had a SpriteKit skView in one view controller and when I pushed another view controller onto the navigation stack the CPU would jump to over 100%. Fixed it by setting `isPaused = true` on the skView before navigating away.